# Socket and InputStream => Connection reset by peer exception

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream

I'm trying to stream an `InputStream`'s data to a socket that acts as proxy. The reason for that is, that I want to play `InputStreams` via the android `MediaPlayer`.

The problem is I always get a **endto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)** exception:

```
    com.prom.gallery.classes.VideoProxy: [VideoProxy-172]   sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
     java.net.SocketException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
         at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterSendto(IoBridge.java:546)
         at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:515)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:504)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266)
         at com.prom.gallery.classes.VideoProxy.processRequest(VideoProxy.java:168)
         at com.prom.gallery.classes.VideoProxy.run(VideoProxy.java:110)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
      Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: sendto failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
         at libcore.io.Posix.sendtoBytes(Native Method)
         at libcore.io.Posix.sendto(Posix.java:176)
         at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.sendto(BlockGuardOs.java:278)
         at libcore.io.IoBridge.sendto(IoBridge.java:513)
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:504) 
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$100(PlainSocketImpl.java:37) 
         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketOutputStream.write(PlainSocketImpl.java:266) 
         at com.prom.gallery.classes.VideoProxy.processRequest(VideoProxy.java:168) 
         at com.prom.gallery.classes.VideoProxy.run(VideoProxy.java:110) 
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

**Question**

How can I solve that? My solution is appended and is based on https://code.google.com/p/npr-android-app/source/browse/Npr/src/org/npr/android/news/StreamProxy.java... I found out I may need a header to keep the socket open, but I don't really know if that's true and how to add that to my solution...

My custom class `IDownloadableMedia` just directly returns a simple stream...

I have multiple sources with videos, some of them allow streams only. For testing I use a source that works with urls as well and I create an `InputStream` like following in the download function: `new URL(url).openStream()`. The url is valid and working!

**Code**

Here's my `VideoProxy` class:

```
public class VideoProxy implements Runnable
{
    public static String createProxyString(VideoProxy proxy, int folderIndex, int mediaIndex,  String uniqueId)
    {
        return String.format("http://127.0.0.1:%d/%s", proxy.getPort(), folderIndex + "-" + mediaIndex + "-" + uniqueId);
    }

    private int port = 0;

    public int getPort()
    {
        return port;
    }

    private boolean mIsRunning = true;
    private ServerSocket mSocket;
    private Thread mThread;

    public void init()
    {
        try
        {
            mSocket = new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[] {127, 0, 0, 1}));
            mSocket.setSoTimeout(5000);
            port = mSocket.getLocalPort();
            L.d(this, "Port " + port);
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            L.e(this, e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            L.e(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void start()
    {
        if (mSocket == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("Proxy has not been initialized!");
        mThread = new Thread(this);
        mThread.start();
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        mIsRunning = false;
        if (mThread != null)
        {
            mThread.interrupt();
            try
            {
                mThread.join(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                L.e(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        L.d(this, "Run...");
        while (mIsRunning)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = mSocket.accept();
                if (client == null)
                    continue;

                L.d(this, "client connected");

                // get data
                String data = readData(client);
                L.d(this, "data: " + data);
                String splitted[] = data.split("-");
                int folderIndex = Integer.parseInt(splitted[0]);
                int mediaIndex = Integer.parseInt(splitted[1]);
                String uniqueId = splitted[2];

                L.d(this, "data splitted: " + folderIndex + ", " + mediaIndex + ", " + uniqueId);

                // get media file
                IDownloadableMedia media = (IDownloadableMedia)RXManager.get().createLoadedSingleFolderObservable(null, null, folderIndex).toBlocking().first().getMedia().get(mediaIndex);

                L.d(this, "media: " + media.getMediaFolder().getName() + " | " + media.getName());

                // download media file
                processRequest(client, media);
            }
            catch (SocketTimeoutException e)
            {
                // Do nothing
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                L.e(this, e);
            }
        }
        L.d(this, "Proxy interrupted - shutting down...");
    }

    private String readData(Socket client)
    {
        InputStream is;
        String firstLine;
        try
        {
            is = client.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            firstLine = reader.readLine();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            L.e(this, e);
            return null;
        }

        if (firstLine == null)
        {
            L.d(this, "Proxy client closed connection without a request.");
            return null;
        }

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(firstLine);
        String method = st.nextToken();
        String uri = st.nextToken();
        L.d(this, uri);
        String realUri = uri.substring(1);
        L.d(this, realUri);
        return realUri;
    }

    private void processRequest(Socket client, IDownloadableMedia downloadableMedia) throws IllegalStateException, IOException
    {
        if (downloadableMedia == null)
            return;
        L.d(this, "downloading...");

        InputStream data = downloadableMedia.download();
        try
        {
            int readBytes = -1;
            // Stream content...
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 50];
            while (mIsRunning && (readBytes = data.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1)
                client.getOutputStream().write(buff, 0, readBytes);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            L.e(this, e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (data != null)
                data.close();
            client.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `to stream an InputStream`. ???? What is streaming an input stream?

Comment: Code is showing what I do. I read data from an input stream in little chunks and forward the data to the sockets stream... Don't know what you mean, if it's the wording or so... Code shows exactly what I want to do... Google calls it streaming in their proxy code comments as well...

Comment: If you think the words I use are wrong, explain me what the correct wording would be..

Comment: Streaming data over a stream. Not streaming a stream.

Comment: Ok, you're right, a little nit picky, but you're right. I think, it's still understandable... But I'll correct it. Would be nice if you could help as well...

Comment: This exception usually means you wrote to a connection that had already been closed by the peer. NB `ServerSocket.accept()` cannot return null, so testing for it is pointless.

Comment: `readData()` opens a BufferedInputStream on the client input stream but only reads one line. The rest is dumped. After that `processRequest()` uses again the clients input stream but will miss that dumped data.

Comment: It only needs to read one line as it reads the url only. It will always be one line only. The data that will be read is defined in the static `createProxyString` functions... It will just contain the data that defines my video... The `processRequest` gets the correct media, created with the data from the `readData` function